# cannot roslaunch rbx2_bringup pi_robot_with_gripper.launch

Tags: ros-package-path, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone. I'm learning *ros_by_example* step by step. When I have installed the packages required by the book and tried the command `roslaunch rbx2_bringup pi_robot_with_gripper.launch sim:=true` there are some mistakes like

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [arbotix_python/arbotix_driver]: arbotix_python
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/shantengfei/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks` `ERROR: cannot launch node of type [arbotix_controllers/gripper_controller]: arbotix_controllers
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/shantengfei/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

I tried with the similiar method like [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/225227/problem-with-gmappinglaunch-file/).But it did'nt work.I have put `source /home/shantengfei/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`in my ~/.bashrc and the ROS_PACKAGES_PATH is `/home/shantengfei/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks`.Could someone give me a solution?Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272861/cannot-roslaunch-rbx2_bringup-pi_robot_with_gripper.launch/) by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-10-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TTDM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28649/ttdm/) on 2017-10-12**:
Well as stated in the answer you found, it means ROS does not find your package, either because it's not installed or because you did not correctly linked it. Did you fixed your other issue, the one for which you asked a question not long ago. it seems to me that this one is linked to the other.

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-10-12**:
Thanks for your reply. I can find the  rbx2 package using roscd/roslaunch, so I think taht this package has be installed.the formmer question is another package that was installed recnetly since I build the workspace I can find the same name folder in ~catkin_ws/build.

**Comment by [TTDM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28649/ttdm/) on 2017-10-13**:
The package that isn't found is not rbx2, it is `arbotix_python`, can you look specially for this one and tell me if you have it ?

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-10-13**:
Sorry I didn't install the package.After I installed the package,it works!Thanks!But another problem I asked still unsloved.Could you please  give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Full answer with a few clarifications, based on the comments :

As stated in your link, this error means that ROS can not find the package  `arbotix_python` either because it is not installed or because it has not been correctly linked.

Please note that this package has nothing to do with the packages from which you launch your launchfiles. Putting launchfiles in a package is simply a way to be able to easily call them ( using `roslaunch <package_name> <launch_name>` ) but you could also put your launch file in any directory, open a terminal in this directory and call `roslaunch <launch_name>` it would work perfectly.

Also note that when calling `arbotix_python/arbotix_driver`, if the package `arbotix_python` is found but not the node `arbotix_driver` then the error is : `Canno't find node arbotix_driver in package arbotix_python`

---

Originally posted by [TTDM](https://answers.ros.org/users/28649/ttdm/) with karma: 267 on 2017-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0